# In tmux, what does <prefix>tab do?

Tags: tmux

In tmux, I hit my prefix followed by the tab key (e.g., `ctrl-b, TAB`). This opened a side pane showing a file tree. What is this mode called?

In searching the documentation, I did not see this keybinding described, only [mentioned](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Modifier-Keys#limitations-of-ctrl-keys).

EDIT: Thanks @pynexj, I should have referred to my `.tmux.conf`, which shows...

```
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sidebar' # prefix+Tab/Backspace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `Tmux Sidebar mode`, you could take a look at this plugin: [tmux-sidebar](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-sidebar)

[image]

### Key bindings

- <kbd>prefix + Tab</kbd> toggle sidebar with a directory tree
- <kbd>prefix + Backspace</kbd>  toggle sidebar and move cursor to it (focus it)